# netbeans 8.2, java debugger error on windows 10

Tags: java, netbeans-8, javascript-debugger

recently, netbeans 8.2 on win10, started giving me some debugger errors for java project.
the project compiles and runs without issues, but when I try to debug it after I put few breakpoints on some methods,
I tried to clean NB cache , I removed build and properties files to have fresh build files , but still getting the follwoing debugger error :

compile-single:

C:........\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1351: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:.........\nbproject\build-impl.xml:858: nbjpdastart doesn't support the nested "modulepath" element.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

I appreciate your help

thanks

Comment: If you suspect it's actually NetBeans and not your Class code then ..... Do you have any older versions of NetBeans still on your system? Perhaps ensure they do not share the same project path or uninstall the older version (save your projects somewhere for that version first). If all fails....save your projects somewhere, uninstall all NetBeans, **Reboot Computer**, download and reinstall NetBeans 8.2. Ensure you get the latest updates.

Comment: nope, I tried all that but I didn't reinstall it ,  I have only NB 8.2 on my system, and current project i'm working on compiles without errors also it generates some results, but I'm trying to debug some methods there, I would prefer to know what's causing this error than going through the last resort solution,,thanks

Comment: also I want to mention that I can debug other projects on NB, just this project specifically is generating this error

Answer (score 0):

Delete these files from the project folder (From Files tab).

build.xml
build-imp.xml
Restart netbeans.

Debug again.